# SharedPreferences String + Int (save and retrieve)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Just a simple app that save (sharedpref) user data and retrieves them into the fields.
The problem was when the user press Retrieve button. I cannot retrieve the data.
So GET method > if (counter.contains(Numb)) > must setText to int
[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZw2z.png)

CODE HERE:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    TextView name;
    TextView email;
    TextView number;
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";
    public static final String Numb = "numbKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"It just saves the data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void Save(View view) {
        String n = name.getText().toString();
        String e = email.getText().toString();
        int numb = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.putInt(Numb, numb);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Number was:"+sharedpreferences.getInt(Numb,numb),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void Get(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, null));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, null));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Numb)) {
            number.setText(""+0);
        }
    }

    public void clear(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        name.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        number.setText("");
    }

}
```

I had setText to 0, because I cannot retrieve the sharedPreferences data.

Comment: don't include code as images, we can't copy that. please edit your question to include it as actual text

Comment: ok, thx for fast response!!

Comment: Dummy question. But how can i post my java code?

Comment: hit [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66134545/edit) on your question (or here in my comment) and paste it as text, you'll see options to edit it as code, you can use 3 spaces or you can make use of the -> ` symbol before and after your code, alternatively i'll help you out this time :)

Comment: Hi my friend , please send your codes for check.

Comment: why do you declare two sharedprefrences Interface Instance?

Comment: It is my 1st try to use SharedPreferences, so I could not imagine that one works in both String and Int values. Thats why I asked it here.

Comment: You can, just use the one :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have edit it and now it has only one. What about the other problem? Which I cannot setText to the saved integer?

Comment: What does the toast message display? Have you tried logging out the value of `numb`? Perhaps you're putting an invalid value in there.
You're also not calling `sharedpreferences.getInt(Numb, 0)`, just setting `number`'s text to 0 if you find `Numb` in your shared prefs.

Comment: The numb value is correct, but I cannot use it in the last method.

Comment: Do you have a log to confirm that? Also, your toast message will display the same value whether or not it finds `Numb`, because you're using a ddefault of the same value, so change that to -1 or something to confirm that's working correctly.

Comment: I retrieved the saved int in the last method by calling into setText ("" + sharedpreferences.getInt(Numb,0))   So it worked Thanks

Comment: Tip for future questions: Don't change your code in the question. If I was to put that as an answer to get points, it would get downvoted because it wouldn't appear to make sense.